# Matrix of checkboxes - only 1 allowed in a row

Tags: javascript, html, matrix

### Task

Create a matrix of checkboxes. The user must be able to select only 1 checkbox in a row or unselect all of them.

[image]

### Solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function switch_checkbox(id_selected, id_pair)
      {
           //if the current checkbox is checked - uncheck the 2-nd checkbox in this row
          if(document.getElementById(id_selected).checked == true)
          {
              document.getElementById(id_pair).checked = false;
          }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="" action="send.php">
      <input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="1-1" value="1-1" onChange="switch_checkbox('1-1', '1-2');"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" id="1-2" value="1-2" onChange="switch_checkbox('1-2', '1-1');"/>
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="2-1" value="2-1" onChange="switch_checkbox('2-1', '2-2');"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" id="2-2" value="2-2" onChange="switch_checkbox('2-2', '2-1');"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you see, the solution is very primitive. Is it possible to make it even simpler?

Comment: why not change to radio buttons?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Because when you select one radio button, you can't unselect all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an unchecked starting condition you can eliminate a parameter and thus drop the conditional:

```
function switch_checkbox(id_pair)
{
    document.getElementById(id_pair).checked = false;
}
```

...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="1-1" value="1-1" onChange="switch_checkbox('1-2');"/>
```